# Why an attribute of an Angular component is automatically updated by a timer instantiated in a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

In my Angular project I have defined:

- a service `myService`
- a component `MainComponent`

### The service `myService`

The service contains a timer that updates, when started, the attribute `currentTime`. The `myService.service.ts` file is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface Parameters {
  currentTime: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class myService {
  acquireParametersTimer!: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
  timerStarted:boolean = false;
  par:Parameters = {
    currentTime: ''
  };

  constructor() {}

  startAcquire(): void {
    if (this.timerStarted == false) {
      this.acquireParametersTimer = setTimeout(() => {this.acquireParameters()}, 1000);
      this.timerStarted = true;
    }
  }

  acquireParameters() {
    const d = new Date();
    this.par.currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    this.acquireParametersTimer = setTimeout(() => {this.acquireParameters()}, 1000);
  }

  getParameters():Parameters {
    return this.par;
  }
}
```

### The component `MainComponent`

The component starts the timer present in the service and call the method `getParameters()` of the service by the method `ngOnInit()`. The file `main.component.ts` is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { myService, Parameters } from 'src/app/services/myService.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  par:Parameters = {
    currentTime: ''
  };

  constructor(private my_service: myService) {
    my_service.startAcquire();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.par = this.my_service.getParameters();
  }
}
```

The file `main.component.html` contains the following code:

```
<div>
    <span>{{par.currentTime}}</span>
</div>
```

If I start the Angular app by the command:

```
> ng serve -o
```

I can see (for example) the time `6:58:12 PM` in the `<span>` tag and after 1000 ms the `<span>` shows the time `6:58:13 PM` and so on. This means that the time increases but I have called the method `getParameters()` of the service only one time.

### Question

If I call the method `getParameters()` only one time in `ngOnInit()`, why the `<span>` tag is updated every 1000 ms? I was expecting that it would be updated only one time when the method `ngOnInit()` is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because setTimeout triggers changeDetection and then every property of your view is updated.

If you dont want this behaviour, you can use runOutsideAngular:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() -> setTimeout(...
```

Comment: In my context this behaviour is OK. Are there some reasons to avoid it?

Comment: No, just because you were asking.